# Keyboard shortcuts with Dvorak keymapping

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-menu

In the Dvorak key layout, Spotlight's shortcut masks the Undo shortcut, and I couldn't fix the problem by changing or disabling shortcut associations. Any advice?

Comment: Spotlight's default shortcut is Comand-Space and Undo is Command-Z. How are these colliding? What key are you hitting? In Dvorak, Spotlight should be the same as QWERTY and Undo should just be moved a little.

Comment: @ CajunLuke the conflict I referred to was with spotlight's Comand-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using "Dvorak - Qwerty ⌘" instead of straight Dvorak.  It uses the Dvorak layout for regular typing, but keeps the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> shortcuts the same as what's printed on your keyboard.

[image: Dvorak - Qwerty]