# "Dvorak - Qwerty ⌘" doesn't work for some applications

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, keybindings, dvorak

I recently switched to Dvorak, and I'm using the Dvorak - Qwerty ⌘ layout. It works in most situations, except some applications don't honor the Qwerty shortcuts. That is, if I were to press what would be command+c on a qwerty keyboard, some applications recognize it as command+j, which is the equivalent key in Dvorak. The applications I've noticed this in are Eclipse and Android Studio, both IDEs, and Terminal.

I'm not sure how to deal with this problem. I would like to find a way to make my keyboard interpret all ⌘+{character} commands as Qwerty commands, but type in Dvorak otherwise. I'd prefer that the solution be extendable to things like ctrl+{character}, for Terminal shortcuts, and be extendable to other layouts, since I'm hoping to make the jump to Programmer Dvorak soon.

Related: [Some dvorak shortcuts aren't working. 10.8.2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84350/some-dvorak-shortcuts-arent-working-10-8-2) (is about Dvorak, not Dvorak - Qwerty ⌘)
[Keyboard shortcuts with Dvorak keymapping](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13871/keyboard-shortcuts-with-dvorak-keymapping) (does not address the issue of keybindings not working)

Comment: I noticed the same thing but I don't have any solution yet. Over time I simply remembered which apps are like this and use Dvorak keys..

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32625196/android-studio-os-x-dvorak-qwerty-layout-shortcuts-switching-doesnt-w/46573576#46573576

Comment: Also true in LibreOffice and GnuCash.

Comment: I'm requesting a way to resolve this through BetterTouchTool.  Any other BTT users, feel free to [comment on the feature request](https://community.folivora.ai/t/create-a-way-to-prevent-btt-from-further-interpreting-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-be-triggered-i-e-a-noremap-option/2390).

Comment: This is the main reason I would argue learning the hybrid is a bad idea.  Just wait to you try sshing/vncing/teamviewring into another persons machinse.  It wrecks complete havock.